# Getting org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException while using apache camel spring-ws

Tags: type-conversion, apache-camel, spring-ws

I am calling SOAP web service by camel spring-ws: component.

`from(DIRECT)
.routeId(ROUTE_ID)
.to("spring-ws:<address>");`

As it will automatically convert the request body to JAXB object and pass into the body of SOAP service but I am getting below error.

**org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: javax.xml.transform.Source but has value: com.example.MyRequest**

**org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: com.example.MyRequest to the required type: javax.xml.transform.Source**

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try adding camel-jaxb to the classpath if your class `MyRequest` has JAXB annotations. Also take a look at the examples for the spring-ws component to find inspiration.

Comment: It was issue with classes which are generated based on wsdl, I regenerate and issue resolved. Thanks